# Vuejs 3 : components scope, and how to provide components to slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'd like in Vue 3 to be able to provide/overwrite existing components to slots by doing something like:

```html
  <ProvideFun>
    <p>
      Hello
      <FunA></FunA>
    </p>
  </ProvideFun>
  <ProvideOtherFun>
    <p>
      Hello
      <FunA></FunA>
    </p>
  </ProvideOtherFun>
```

in order to be allowed to use some components (here `<FunA>`) inside others components (here `<ProvideFun>` and `<ProvideOtherFun>`). Note that `ProvideFun` and `ProvideOtherFun` may provide **different** versions of the `<FunA>` component.

How could I do something like that?

You can find a [demo here.](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: I don't understand. Can you clarify? Seems like your example will work after you import the `FunA` Component into `App.vue`. `import FunA from './FunA.vue'`

Comment: So basically I want to be able to define multiple component "styles" (not just css), so that FunA in ProvideFun gives a different component than when FunA is inserted inside ProvideOtherFun. If I register FunA in App.vue, then the same component would be used everywhere, which is not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "styles" then?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1: Provide/inject components

The parent (i.e., `ProvideFun` or `ProvideOtherFun`) could [`provide`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#provide) its own component definition (named `"comp"`) to be used in `FunA`:

```html
<!-- ProvideFun.vue -->
<script setup>
import { provide } from 'vue'
import CompA from './CompA.vue'
          
provide('comp', CompA)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>
    Provide fun
  </h1>
  <slot />
</template>
```

```html
<!-- ProvideOtherFun.vue -->
<script setup>
import { provide } from 'vue'
import CompB from './CompB.vue'
          
provide('comp', CompB)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>
    Provide other fun
  </h1>
  <slot />
</template>
```

Make `FunA.vue` a [`<component>`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component) wrapper that [`inject`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html#inject)s the `"comp"` component definition from a parent:

```html
<!-- FunA.vue -->
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'
       
const comp = inject('comp')
</script>

<template>         
  <component :is="comp" />
</template>
```

This requires registering the `FunA` placeholder component before it could be used in `ProvideFun`/`ProvideOtherFun`:

```html
<script setup>
import ProvideFun from './ProvideFun.vue'
import ProvideOtherFun from './ProvideOtherFun.vue'
        
import FunA from './FunA.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <ProvideFun>
    <p>
      Hello
      <FunA />
    </p>
  </ProvideFun>
  
  <ProvideOtherFun>
    <p>
      Hello
      <FunA />
    </p>
  </ProvideOtherFun>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

### Option 2: Components via slot props

Bind the `CompA` component definition as a [slot prop](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component) (named `"FunA"`) in `ProvideFun.vue`, and `CompB` in `ProvideOtherFun.vue`:

```html
<!-- ProvideFun.vue -->
<script setup>
import CompA from './CompA.vue'
</script>

<template> 
  <slot :FunA="CompA">
</template>
```

```html
<!-- ProvideOtherFun.vue -->
<script setup>
import CompB from './CompB.vue'
</script>

<template> 
  <slot :FunA="CompB">
</template>
```

Then use a [`<component>`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component) to render it in the parent:

```html
<script setup>
import ProvideFun from './ProvideFun.vue'
import ProvideOtherFun from './ProvideOtherFun.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <ProvideFun>           
    <template v-slot="{ FunA }">
      <p>
        Hello            
        <component :is="FunA" />
      </p>
    </template>
  </ProvideFun>
  
  <ProvideOtherFun>      
    <template v-slot="{ FunA }">
      <p>
        Hello            
        <component :is="FunA" />
      </p>
    </template>
  </ProvideOtherFun>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks! Ouh, your first solution is tricky... ^^ I love the syntax (notably that it does not need `<component>`), but the problem is that I need to `import FunA from './FunA.vue'`. And in real life, basically, I won't have much control over the code in template (I read it from a kind of markdown file like in the slidev project) and it will be hard to automatically know which component I should import or not... The second solution has the exact opposite problem: the syntax is not as nice (in markdown I would need to use `<template>`... which is not ideal... but at least I don't need import.

Comment: @tobiasBora In slidev, components from `components/*.vue` are globally registered automatically, so you don't need to import or register the components yourself (see [slidev demo of the above](https://stackblitz.com/edit/slidev-dynamic-component?file=slides.md)).